# Receiving a null value from android in php file

Tags: php, android, json

I have written a code in android as as well as in php..while sending data from emulator and php in localhost it is working fine..but when i change the server to www.xxx.com/test.php, it is sending a null value from a real android device and null value is saving in the mysql database..

What might be the problem?

Thanks in advance..

My Code:
InputStream is;

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://xxx.com/usercheck.php");
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

JSONObject json = new JSONObject(); 


    try {

        json.put("username",txtusername.getText().toString()); 
        json.put("password",txtpassword.getText().toString());           

        List<NameValuePair> parameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userpwd_value",json.toString()));

        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(parameters));  

        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        String response = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);
        //This is the response from a php application
        String reverseString = response;
            Toast.makeText(this, "response" + reverseString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "CPE response " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "IOE response " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php
  require_once('config.php');
    //$data = file_get_contents('php://input');//tried this also
   $a=$_POST['userpwd_value']; //accesing value from android
   $b=json_decode($a); //decoding android value using JSON

  $username=$b->{'username'}; //assigning username from android to a variable  
  $password=$b->{'password'};//assigning password from android to a variable  

  //echo $username.$password;
  if($username=="" || $password=="")
    $output[]=array("value"=>"false");
  else
    {   

      $check = mysql_query("select userid,password from xxx where userid='".$username."'");

      $row = mysql_fetch_array($check);

      if($row['userid']==$username && $row['password']==$password)
        {
          $output[]=array("value"=>"true");
        } 
      else 
      { 
          $output[]=array("value"=>"false");
      }
      print(json_encode($output));
   }  
 ?>
```

Comment: Please show your code...

Comment: Post the code to get the responses:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case I can do this way,

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

httppost.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs,HTTP.UTF_8));
        // Execute HTTP Post Request
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        // get response entity
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        // convert entity response to string
 if (entity != null) {

    InputStream is = entity.getContent();
    // convert stream to string
    result = convertStreamToString(is); 
    result = result.replace("\n", "");
    }
```

Hope this will help you.. Thnx.

Answer (score 0):

In a case like this, the key is localizing the problem, finding out on which layer it occurs.  The first step would be to print or otherwise debug all $_POST data in the beginning of php file, so you'll know if and in what form the (almost)raw data gets to server. 
You can guess, where to go next:

- if tha data arrives properly to php, you should debug, what happens to it later in your php
- if it doesn't, go debug variables in your Android script, starting from the point where Android finally posts.

Just checking your code, line-by-line, is not the way to go.